# ArcPy: Connect to MySQL database

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, mysql, odbc

My project aims at updating automatically point feature classes in a ESRI local geodatabase using MySQL tables with X,Y coordinates. The updates should be launched with the Windows task-scheduler.
I am following closely the process described on [blogs.esri.com](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/07/30/scheduling-a-scrip/), using ArcGIS 10.1 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard. I work in folder where I have full R/W permissions.

I have created the OLE DB connexion in ArcCatalog (following this [GIS-SE post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27985/establishing-a-mysql-connection-in-arcgis-10)), and a ModelBuilder to run the conversion process. It works fine when launched in ArcCatalog.

I have created this ArcPy script to launch the ModelBuilder :

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import arcpy

    # Import the toolbox containing the model.  
    arcpy.ImportToolbox(r"c:\myTBX.tbx", "myTBX")

    # Run the model "myTool".  The model has two parameters:
    #    1- the geodatabase to update
    #    2- the input connection file to MySQL:

    out_geodatabase = r"c:\mygeodatabase.gdb"
    in_connection = r"c:\myConnection.odc"

    arcpy.myTool_myTBX(out_geodatabase, in_connection)

    print "process complete"
```

What I get is an errror message that says that the connection to MySQL does not exist or is not supported: the behaviour is different is I call the Model from within ArGIS (runs without error) or from ArcPy outside a user session (the connection to MySql is not recognized).

Does anyone know why this is happening, and how I could resolve it?

Comment: It seems you could implement the whole workflow in Python instead of using ModelBuilder - as you see it can get harder to troubleshoot.

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov Can you advise on how to connect to MySQL in Python?

Comment: You can try using [MySQL Connector/Python](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-introduction.html) or [pyodbc](http://mkleehammer.github.io/pyodbc/) to connect to MySQL.

Comment: I notice that your toolbox,gdb and odc files are on the ROOT of your c:\ drive. You don't say which version of Windows you are using. I've had problems with permissions on windows 8.1 when accessing files on the root of c:\, so I would suggest moving everything into a folder you have read/write access such as c:\temp\projectX. Worth a try?

Comment: @Hélène, you would just use the same geoprocessing tools you use in ModelBuilder in Python instead using arcpy package.

Comment: @Hornbydd : I have simplified paths for legibility in this post - the database and odc file are however in a folder where I have full permissions. I'll edit the post with the windows version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run the process on a server where both the 64-bits and 32-bits versions of Python are installed, as the server holds both ArcGIS Desktop and ArcGIS Server.

By default, the 64-bit version is launched, and my script fails. I forced the 32-bit version use by launching the script from the command line, and the update went through successfully.

```
    C:\>C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\python.exe C:\myScript.py
```

This solution is derived from http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011711. However, setting the 32-bit python as the default program did not suffice.